# Getting error when trying to install react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-v5

[This is what I am getting when running the installation command in my command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R49jt.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur because you haven't installed react-navigation. You can try:

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
npm install react-navigation
```

I hope it will be useful to you.

Comment: This is actually happening when I am trying to install react-navigation